# preg_replace dynamic regular exp variable not working

Tags: php, regex

this the array which are used in the loop. the first foreach for numeric array and second array is for the associative array.

```
 Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [CORPORATEID] => 3
            [menuRightBorder] => 7DFFEB
            [menuTextColor] => FF00C8
            [submenuTextColorHover] => 666666
            [buttonBg] => F6FDFE
            [widgetBg] => FFFFFF
            [helpContainerBg] => FCFCFC
            [menuBg] => 3BFF4B
            [menuHover] => 717171
            [submenuTextColor] => EBEBEB
            [innerSubmenuTextColorHover] => 661010
            [iconColor] => 661304
            [widgetTickColor] => FFFFFF
            [helpContainerHelpTextColor] => 21FF59
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [CORPORATEID] => 0
            [menuRightBorder] => ff0000
            [menuTextColor] => fff
            [submenuTextColorHover] => 003366
            [buttonBg] => fe0000
            [widgetBg] => ff0000
            [helpContainerBg] => cfdffc
            [menuBg] => ff0000
            [menuHover] => 054271
            [submenuTextColor] => fff
            [innerSubmenuTextColorHover] => 003366
            [iconColor] => 003366
            [widgetTickColor] => ff0000
            [helpContainerHelpTextColor] => 000
        )

)


    foreach($_Aarray as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $innervalue) {
         $css=preg_replace('~\b'.$key.'\b~',$innervalue,$cssContent);
    }
}
```

In the above code preg_replace the regular expression does not replace in the $cssContent.

Comment: ... i think some values of your variables could help. We don't have a crystal ball or magic skills ;)

Comment: added array with values edited the question...

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I try to guess you $cssContent...

First, you overwrite your $css every iteration. Every step one key will be replaced (if a match is found), the result will be stored in the `$css` and in the next iteration of the loop the one *other* key will be replaced und and the result will *overwrite* your old result.

Second, if that are really your loop and array-data, then (if you wouldn't overwrite your result every iteration) only the first array will have an effect, because after the first big iteration all keys will be replaced (cause you have the same keys in the second array).

To solve the first problem, your loop should look like

```
$css = $cssContent;
foreach($_Aarray as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $innervalue) {
       $css = preg_replace('~\b'.$key.'\b~', $innervalue, $css);
    }
}
```

To solve the second problem, we need more information about your plan.